# Magento: how to add a static block on top of the image for a particular product using the product id

Tags: image, magento, templates, block, product

I would like to add a static block on top of a particular product image using the product id. the static block should also appear everywhere the product image is display that is product view, upsell, related product etc.

more important i should do it programmatic without changing anything in the respective template .phtml file where the product image is rendered.

Comment: Hi, what have been you doing so far?

Comment: can you be more specific about your question

Comment: i have create a table which store different product id with different text according to some condition. now i want to display this text on top of the product image corresponding to the product id. how could i display it programmatically everywhere the product image is shown(product list, view, upsell, related product etc..) without changing their .phtml file.